Invariant Timestamp Counter is synchronised between cores of the same CPU?
I'm interested in how Invariant TSC behaves on a multi-core CPU, on a classic PC with a single physical CPU.
The only thing I could find is that its frequency is constant and the same for all CPU cores(right?).
But I still have questions about whether the value of its internal counter is the same for all CPU cores, especially since the other cores start after the first one?
And in the end, can the kernel just take it and use it as a global clock, similar to HPET? Does it require some form of synchronisation and configuration on the kernel side?
And is this all true as whether it's Intel or AMD?
I have tried reading Intel documentation but unfortunately I have not been able to find an answer to these questions.

The disappointing answer is, it depends.  The RDTSC counter is writable through machine-specific registers, so the not-first CPUs can sync their value with the primary CPU at startup.  Originally, say 20 years ago, the counters were not synchronized, and one would often find values differed.  You had to restrict yourself too a single CPU to use the counter.

CPU TSC fetch operation especially in multicore-multi-processor environment says that on Intel, all TSCs in a package are already synced at bootup (Intel Nehalem and newer, with constant and invariant TSC CPU features: fixed frequency, and doesn't stop when the core clock stops.)  Apparently most systems do boot up with the TSCs synced between all cores even on different sockets, by distributing the RESET signal with precise timing.  Another commenter said in 2012 an AMD Phenom didn't have sync between its own cores.

It's been a while since I looked carefully at that linked Q&A; I think it's a duplicate but I'll hold off for now; let me know if it leaves anything unanswered.

My answer on How to get the CPU cycle count in x86_64 from C++? also links some Intel forum threads whose URLs have changed; might be available on the wayback machine.  (Intel is terrible about keeping URLs valid for interesting stuff on their site.)

@TimRoberts, The iTSC functions at the same frequency for all cores and as far as I understand counts the elapsed time since RESET, the question is, does RESET happen for all cores at the same time even if they are not inited by OS?

@PeterCordes, I hope this is indeed the case on modern processors, however I would like to find some sort of statement about this in the spec.

For newer processors, good behavior can be expected.  RDTSC was not nearly so friendly before about 2010.  On some chips, the counter actually counted cycles, which meant when the clock changed for power management, the RDTSC rate changed, and systems with multiple chips were not synced.  That's why Microsoft's QueryPerformanceCounter does not use it.

@TimRoberts, Since the question was about iTSC, I was immediately sure that the frequency is the same for all cores at all times, I just wondered if the counter value is the same for all cores.
